# ggplot not rendering plot correctly

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have used a simple CSV table and made a plot with the desired colors and dots, but I cannot find the solution to connect the dots with a line.

```
#----Import data----#
DS <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Iqbalpr/Tugas-Kuliah--UIN/main/Data%20Skripsi%20Gender%20%2B%20Negara%20(CSV).csv")
View(DS)
ncol(DS)
nrow(DS)

#----Check and convert column type----#
str(DS) # Check Column
DS$ID <- as.factor(DS$ID )
DS$Gender <- as.factor(DS$Gender)
DS$Tahun <- as.integer(DS$Tahun)
DS$Inflasi <- as.numeric(DS$Inflasi)
DS$Pengangguran <- as.numeric(DS$Pengangguran)
DS$`GDP growth rate` <- as.numeric(DS$`GDP growth rate`)
DS$`GDP per Capita` <- as.numeric(DS$`GDP per Capita`)
str(DS) # Check Column Again

#----Plot----#
p <- ggplot(DS) + aes(x = Tahun, y = AHH, group = Negara, color = Negara) + geom_point()
p
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIjNS.png)

Now I want the dots connected with the same color as the dots and I use this code:

```
p <- ggplot(DS) + aes(x = Tahun, y = AHH, group = Negara, color = Negara) + geom_point() + geom_line()
p
```

but I get a very strange line like this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M69KG.png)
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you have two values per country because of your Gender column which will result in the graph you have. An option is to use `facet_wrap` to plot it for each Gender like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(DS) + 
  aes(x = Tahun, y = AHH, group = Negara, color = Negara) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line() + 
  facet_wrap(~Gender)
p
```

Output:

[image]